# Why use 'this.' to define a function inside a method inside a class (in React.js)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am currently learning React.js, and I'm trying to understand the instance in [this code](https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/amqdNA?editors=0010) where, for example, the code is provided as:

```
componentDidMount() {
this.timerID = setInterval(
  () => this.tick(),
  1000
);
}
```

What I'm struggling with is why couldn't we just type:

```
componentDidMount() {
setInterval(
  () => this.tick(),
  1000
);
}
```

Why do we have to use the 'this.'?

Comment: who said You cannot? in Your example `this.timerID` variable is member of class instance (object) and the idea to have instance based `timerID` is to have ability to stop the interval. using `clearInterval(this.timerID)` otherwise You cannot have the pointer and cannot stop scheduler (interval). Summarize: with first example You can stop interval using `clearInterval(this.timerID)` in second example You cannot since You've not variable that represents interval to clear it.

Comment: @num8er I think this should be posted as an answer. OP didn't say you cannot do it that way, but what the reasoning for the first example is.

Comment: @Bradmage I know. But I don't want to get reputation on too simple answers. (: Even I would like to vote for closing the question.

Comment: @Bradmage Thank you so much, you've cleared up a lot for me!

Comment: Not a problem, but you credited the wrong person. @num8er posted the information.

Comment: Apologies, thank you @num8er!!

Comment: @217582  You're welcome (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have the timer ID you can use [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) on it

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like you proposed. Assigning the result of `setInterval()` was probably done for some other future purpose, like calling `clearInterval`.